# mysql post from html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get my sql to post information from a html form into my database however keep getting:

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 29
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  247624  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0
```

The code i am using is:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
   Name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
// This is the connection to my database
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'shane', 'diamond89');
if (!$con){
   die('Could not Connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// This selects which database i want to connect to
$selected = mysql_select_db("shane",$con);
if (!$con){
   die("Could not select data");
}

// This inserts new information to the Database
$name = $_POST['name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('id', '$name')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error' . mysql_error());

// This closes my connection
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: This also adds a blank record to my table

Comment: Add this to the start of your code: echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST); This should give you an idea of what html is passing to your script. PHP seems ok.. lets check..

Comment: Post the table definition as well.

Answer (score 6):

Your form has an input named `firstname` not `name`, so `$_POST['name']` should be `$_POST['firstname']`

change

```
    // This inserts new information to the Database
    $name = $_POST['name'];
```

to

```
   // This inserts new information to the Database
   $name = $_POST['firstname'];
```

Comment: still getting: ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 29
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0006 247632 {main}( ) ..\insert.php:0

Answer (score 1):

Name:

```
<?php
// This is the connection to my database
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'shane', 'diamond89');
if (!$con){
die('Could not Connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// This selects which database i want to connect to
$selected = mysql_select_db("shane",$con);
if (!$con){
die("Could not select data");
}
if($_POST['firstname'])
{
// This inserts new information to the Database
$name = $_POST['firstname'];

$query = "INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('id', '$name')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error' . mysql_error());

// This closes my connection
mysql_close($con)
}
?>
```

Comment: still getting: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 27
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0005 248000 {main}( ) ..\insert.php:0

Comment: use if(isset($_POST['firstname']))

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting values after submit the form?. Try:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you view your page, $_POST is undefined as the form hasn't been posted. 
Once the user submits, the $_POST will be valid.

You should try to see if the values exists before using it.

eg

```
if (isset($_POST['xxx']))
{
/* Do Something */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted the answer by AB Åttìtúðê Þêrfëçt that corrects your PHP code. However, this might help:

Through wamp tray icon, open php.ini file and find

```
    error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Replace w/

```
    error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Then save file and restart wamp

From: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,72161,72201

Comment: That's not really helpful, because it's just telling PHP to shut up about the programmer's neglectfulness ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your help i worked this out with a bit of hair pulling. I came up with

```
    <?php
// This is the connection to my database
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'shane', 'diamond89');
if (!$con){
die('Could not Connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// This selects which database i want to connect to
$selected = mysql_select_db("shane",$con);
if (!$con){
die("Could not select examples");
}

$name=$_POST['firstname'];

$sql="INSERT INTO test1(name)VALUES('$name')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='sql_table.php'>Back to main page</a>";
```

}

```
else {
echo "ERROR";
```

}

```
// This closes my connection
mysql_close($con)
?>
```